# Taylor expansion of $\log(3+x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Using the standard result of $\log$ find the taylor expansion of $$\log{(3+x)}$$

Now I believe $$\log{(1+x)} = \log{(1+x)} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^{n}$$

So to find $\log{(3+x)}$ let $y=2+x$ then we are finding $\log{(1+y)}$ which we have a standard result for:

$$\log{(1+y)} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}y^{n} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(2+x)^{n}$$ $$ = 2 + x - \frac{(2+x)^{2}}{2} + \frac{(2+x)^{3}}{3} - \ldots$$

but the taylor expansion of $\log{(3+x)}$ is $$\log{(3+x)} = \log{(3)}+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^{2}}{18}+\frac{x^{3}}{81} - \ldots$$

which is drastically different to my own, what is wrong and why does this not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\displaystyle 3 + x = 3\left(1 + {x \over 3}\right)$. Then

$$\log(3 + x) = \log 3 + \log\left(1 + {x \over 3}\right) = \log 3 + \frac{x}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2\cdot 3^2} + \frac{x^3}{3 \cdot 3^3} + \cdots$$

Comment: Thank you, why does it not work to take $y=2+x$?

Comment: @user2850514 In general terms that would also work. The question is whether you want an expansion centered on $x = 0$ or $x = -2$. It appears from the target answer in your question you wanted the former. However the question as asked here is slightly ambiguous in that regard (and therefore not necessarily your 'fault', but the person who set it).

Answer (score 2):

$|y| = |2+x|$ can be greater than $1$ for $x \approx 0$, so the formula does not hold. To use $1+x$ you make sure $|x| < 1$

Answer (score 2):

There is no single Taylor series for a function. A Taylor series always comes with a point for which we have expanded the function about.

The Taylor series for a function $f$ about the point $x=a$ is defined as

$$f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$'th derivative of $f$.

The first series you quote is the Taylor series for $f$ about $a=-2$. The second series is the Taylor series about $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$log(1+x)^{-1}=-log(\frac{1}{1+x})$ which allows you to expand if $|1+x|\ge2$.

Answer (score 1):

the series you have written is valid for $-3 < x < -1$ so that $|2+x| < 1$ and the series $\ln(3 + x) = \ln 3 + x/3 - x^2/18+ \cdots $ is valid for $|x| < 3$ both series are valid in their respective domains. even in their common domain of validity, their truncation may give different approximations.